# How to test Eclipse RCP application automatically? Like SWTBot

Tags: eclipse-rcp, automated-tests, swtbot

I have a Eclipse RCP application. It writes some files on disk and sends emails. 
I want to write automated tests for the application, so I was planning to use SWTBot for automatic testing of SWT GUI, but is it possible to write test cases in SWTBot for verifiying files and emails or do I need to use some other framework for this?

I should accomplish something like:
1) Click "new email" and input address and subject
2) Click "Send"
3) Another thread is simulating tcp socket and listening to specific port and veryfying the email is sent.

Comment: As per my understanding you can handle only UI part in SWTBot, To test email sending and verifying the files on local machine is not possible. Even SWTBot doesn't support Native dialogs.

Comment: Yes, SWTBot does not support anything else than UI testing, but there are other testing frameworks that must support.